# MUI export print - datagrid

Tags: reactjs, mui-datatable

I am new in programming and also in meterial UI - React

I tried to apply the dataGrid, export(Download as CSV and Print) component to my project

My rows props is based on my state and my state value came from https request via useEffect. but when I try to print tha value on dataGrid the page will corrupts and freeze and need to close it and start into new page.

any suggestion to solve this problem? I tried to search it but I can't find anything. Thanks

Comment: why don't you paste your tried code?

Comment: I already did it, but still the same error.

Comment: even it is static data it still freezing when I click the print